# How to set a dynamic name in ng-form

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a component with a ng-form. I want to set the ng-form name dynamically so I outside the component the people can access easily to the ng-form value.

Example:

```
<form name="formName">
<component name="componentName"></component>
</form>
```

And inside the component I have

```
<ng-form name="{{$ctrl.name}}">
// Some inputs with special validation 
</ng-form>
```

But every time I try to access the $ctrl.name inside my component is undefined, or just a string not a form with inputs inside.

I use TYPESCRIPT:

```
@Component(app, {
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
  bindings: {
    value: '=?ngModel',
    name: '@',
    required: '=?ngRequired',
    disabled: '=?ngDisabled',

  },
})
    console.log(this.name); ///A string, but no a form so I can manipulate it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following sample code

Component.js

```
angular.module('myApp').component('component', {
   bindings: {            
        name: '@'
    },
  template:
    '<ng-form name={{$ctrl.name}}><input name="txtfirst" value="John"/><input type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.getFormData()"></ng-form>',
  controller: function($scope) {
      console.log(this.name);   

     this.getFormData = function(){
          console.log($scope[this.name]); 
     }        
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<component name="frmNameTest"></component>
```

Comment: Yes, the code works but is not what I want. I obtain a  string with the form name and I want the form object with a dynamic name so I can manipulate inside the controller.

Comment: Please check updated code. "$scope[this.name]" will give form object.

Comment: That works on form but I want to use in NG-FORM and I dont know how I can use properly.

Comment: Changed form to ng-form and It's working. Please let me know your view if any

Answer (score 2):

If you want the form object be available on the controller, rather than scope, then you can do as above except the form declaration would be

```
<form name="$ctrl[{{$ctrl.name}}]">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: yes... this fixed it.... was getting some strangeness  in my errors object: required: [undefined] now fixed! :D